# please give me an specific example about "a lattice model of secure information flow"?

Tags: network

Currently I read the paper ["A lattice model of secure information flow"](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~trj1/cse543-f13/docs/denning_lattice.pdf), but I think this paper is so abstract. Could you please give me an specific example and describe what the secure information flow is in a computer system?

Comment: Could you add links to the paper - it might help you get more answers?

Comment: Yes, here is the link http://www.cse.psu.edu/~trj1/cse543-f13/docs/denning_lattice.pdf